# How to save image to gallery in Android?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2

I've created a camera with Android Studio and want to save the taken image to the gallery.
I use the `Camera2 Api` and don't really know how to save the picture.
Moreover, I don't know, where my photo gets stored. The App says: `Saved: /storage/emulated/1.jpg`.

Here is some code:

```
mFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "1.jpg");

private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener
        = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        mBackgroundHandler.post(new ImageSaver(reader.acquireNextImage(), mFile));
    }

};

private static class ImageSaver implements Runnable {

    /**
     * The JPEG image
     */
    private final Image mImage;
    /**
     * The file we save the image into.
     */
    private final File mFile;

    public ImageSaver(Image image, File file) {
        mImage = image;
        mFile = file;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
        buffer.get(bytes);
        FileOutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
            output.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            mImage.close();
            if (null != output) {
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The next problem is, that I don't know how to store more photos. In this case, `1.jpg` is always overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

To add your picture in the gallery :

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

[See here](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskGallery)

To save multiple pictures generate a new name for every new picture (use the date and time or an UUID)